# How to get the image name of the ImageView in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I have two ImageViews that pictures change by clicking. I need the name of the current image of each ImageView and if the names equal to a condition show text in TextView. how can I do that?
here is my code:

```
var imageViewUf = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
var imageViewLf = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView2);
imageViewUf.Click += (e, o) => {
    ++numberUf;
    if (numberUf == 1)
       imageViewUf.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.a03SF9AP56UF);
    else if (numberUf == 2)
       imageViewUf.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.a01SF5BP52UF);};


imageViewLf.Click += (e, o) => {
    ++numberUf;
    if (numberUf == 1)
       imageViewUf.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.a02SF8BP55LF);
    else if (numberUf == 2)
       imageViewUf.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.a03SF9BP56LF);};

if(image1 equal a03SF9AP56UF && image2 equal a03SF9BP56DF)
   textView1.Text = "something";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue with this is that once you assign an Imageview a Resource, it's first converted into a Bitmap and then applied to your Image so there is no way to just get the resource id that is being used by that Widget. What you can do instead is use the Tag property.

```
 if (numberUf == 1)
   imageViewUf.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.a03SF9AP56UF);
   imageViewUf.Tag = yourImageTag; // this should be a string
else if (numberUf == 2)
   imageViewUf.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.a01SF5BP52UF);
   imageViewUf.Tag= somethingDifferentTag; // same as above
```

And then when you need to compare just compare your tag instead:

```
if(image1.Tag == yourImageTag && image2.Tag == somethingDifferentTag)
```